# Is it possible to change font for an edit control without affecting the other lines?

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

Hello I want to know if it is possible to change the font of an edit control for some lines only without affecting the remaining:

In my `Edit control` I have a text but I want some headlines and titles in bigger font and bold while the other lines are with smaller font.

I tried `SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, MAKELPARAM(0, true));`
But it sets the whole text in the passed in font.

I thought some messing up with `SelectObject(hDcEdit, hFont);` But I don't know if it is correct and how.

Comment: No.  Consider RichEdit.

Comment: @HansPassant: Ok thank you very much. I'll read some documents on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard [Edit Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458.aspx) (think, Notepad) does not support what you are looking for.  It only supports one Font for the entire text.

What you are looking for is a [RichEdit Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787605.aspx) instead (think, Wordpad), and in particular its [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774230.aspx) message, which can be used to apply different formatting (including fonts, colors, etc) to different sections of text.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working with the default Editcontrol, but you can use a Richeditcontrol

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>

HINSTANCE relib = LoadLibrary("riched32.dll");
if (relib == NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "couldn't load richedit32.dll", "", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

hEdit = CreateWindow(RICHEDIT_CLASS, "", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE | 
ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL, 0, 0, 200, 200, hWnd, NULL, 
NULL, NULL);
```

Now to set the font to your Richeditcontrol use:

```
CHARFORMAT2 cf;
memset(&cf, 0, sizeof cf);
cf.cbSize = sizeof cf;
cf.dwMask = CFM_FACE;
wsprintf(cf.szFaceName, "Arial"); //Here you can set the fontname you wont (C:/Windows/Fonts)
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&cf);
```